# Trying to add a custom Node to the end of a LinkedList recursively

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

Hi I seem to having trouble adding custom nodes to the back of my l inked list. The custom node is called `ListNode` and the linked list is called `AddressList`.

My program does not crash or throw any exceptions but it does not add a `ListNode` to the end of my `AddressList`. My `addToFront` method works but not my `addToBack` method. I just need someone to look at my `addToBack` method and see where I am going wrong.

I also have to do this recursively. Each `ListNode` has some values (`name`, `telephoneNum`, `email`, `address`, `dob`) and also a `Next` value which is a `ListNode` that should point to the next `ListNode` in the `AddressList`.

This is my code:

```
public ListNode(String name, String telephoneNum, String email, String address, String dob) {
    this.name = name;
    this.telephoneNum = telephoneNum;
    this.email = email;
    this.address = address;
    this.dob = dob;
}

public ListNode getNext() {
   return next;
}

public void setNext(ListNode link) {
   next = link;
}
```

The code section above is the constructor for the `ListNode` and the methods to get and set the next link in the `AddressList`.

```
public void addToBack(String name, String telephoneNum, String email, String address, String dob) {
    /*Base case.*/
    /*If the next node in the AddressList is null add the ListNode to that node.*/
    if(currentNode.getNext() == null) {
        currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
        currentNode = new ListNode(name, telephoneNum, email, address, dob);
    }
    /*Recursive case.*/
    /*If the AddressList still has nodes after the currentNode, keep going.*/
    else {
        currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
        addToBack(name, telephoneNum, email, address, dob);
    }
    currentNode = head;
}
```

Above is my `addToBack` method. I just don't understand why my program isn't throwing an exception or adding the `ListNode` to the back of the `AddressList`. Any feedback will be appreciated.

Comment: You are not setting new node as next node anywhere. So there is no link between nodes.  More attention on your null check block

Comment: What is `currentNode`. In your question you do not talk about that piece of information: normally a linked list only has a reference to the first node (the *head*). It looks as if you use a *continuation-state* in the state of your class. That can become problematic design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the offending piece of code...

```
  /*Base case.*/
   /*If the next node in the AddressList is null add the ListNode to that node.*/
   if(currentNode.getNext() == null)
   {
      currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
      currentNode = new ListNode(name, telephoneNum, email, address, dob);
   }
```

If you reach the null case you need to set the next node as a new node ... I propose something like this

```
   if(currentNode.getNext() == null)
   {
      currentNode.setNext(new ListNode(name, telephoneNum, email, address, dob));
   }
```

Comment: That worked thank you!! Recursive makes my head spin.

Answer (score 0):

## Separate responsibilities

I think you first better separate some responsibilities: instead of each time using arguments to advance the information of that user one step further, construct a node in advance, and pass this to the recursive method. This will boost performance a bit and make the call stack smaller. So something like:

```
public void addToBack(String name, String telephoneNum, String email, String address, String dob) {
    addToBack(new ListNode(name,telephoneNum,email,address,dob));
}
```

And then you need to work out a method like:

```
public void addToBack(ListNode newNode) {
    //TODO: implement
    //...
}
```

## Avoid method state (or continuation state) in objects

A second problem is that you're `AddressList` seems to have a field `currentNode` that is modified in the recursive process. This can be very problematic: it attaches a ***continuation-state* to your `AddressList`**. Now imagine that later you want to make your class multi-threaded, then these threads will concurrently read and manipulate this field. In short: it is bad design, use a method variable and/or parameter.

So the first thing we do is fetch the head of the `AddressList` and use that:

```
public void addToBack(ListNode newNode) {
    this.addToBack(this.head,newNode);
}
```

This is not sufficient: an empty linked list has *no head*: `head` is a `null` reference. In that case we simply set the `head` to the `newNode` and we're done. so we rewrite this to:

```
public void addToBack(ListNode newNode) {
    if(this.head == null) {
        this.head = newNode;
    } else {
        this.addToBack(this.head,newNode);
    }
}
```

Now evidently we still need to implement the core method:

```
public void addToBack(ListNode current, ListNode newNode) {
    //TODO: implement
    //...
}
```

## Implement the core-method

As you identified yourself, there are basically two cases: the base case in which the `.getNext()` of `current` is `null`, an the one where it is not: for the base case, we simply set the `.setNext` of `current` to our `newNode`:

```
if(current.getNext() == null) {
    current.setNext(newNode);
}
```

In the latter case, we advance: we fetch the `.getNext` node, and call the method recursively:

```
else {
    addToBack(current.getNext(),newNode);
}
```

Or all together:

```
public void addToBack(String name, String telephoneNum, String email, String address, String dob) {
    //separate responsibilities, by constructing the node first
    addToBack(new ListNode(name,telephoneNum,email,address,dob));
}

public void addToBack(ListNode newNode) {
    //do not use a continuation state in a class, fetch the head, inspect the head and if not null pass to the recursion method
    if(this.head == null) {
        this.head = newNode;
    } else {
        this.addToBack(this.head,newNode);
    }
}

public void addToBack(ListNode current, ListNode newNode) {
    //generic method that adds the node at the end
    if(current.getNext() == null) {//base case: current is the last node
        current.setNext(newNode);
    } else {//recursive case, current is not the next node
        addToBack(current.getNext(),newNode);
    }
}
```

You can make the last method a bit faster by preventing to call the `.getNext` method twice:

```
public void addToBack(ListNode current, ListNode newNode) {
    //generic method that adds the node at the end
    ListNode nx = current.getNext();
    if(nx == null) {//base case: current is the last node
        current.setNext(newNode);
    } else {//recursive case, current is not the next node
        addToBack(nx,newNode);
    }
}
```

but that's just a detail that will have very limited impact.